# how to play a sound file after another sound in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I play a sound file after another sound ends? If I do it like

```
first.play();
second.play();
```

Both the sounds play at the same time. I want to play `first.play()` and when it ends, starts `second.play()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
first.addEventListener('ended', function(){
    second.play();
});
first.play();
```

Comment: But if I wanted to play many files in succession I would be looking at call back hell. Any way to introduce .then() promise like syntax?

Comment: @whamsicore please have a look at my answer which makes use of .then()

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend kind of something:

```
// if using jQuery:
var audios = $('audio');

audios.each(function(idx){
    $(this).bind('ended', function(){
        var next = audios.get(idx+1);
        if(next){
            next.get(0).play();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a promise with a timeout:

```
const playPromise = first.play()

playPromise.then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {second.play()}, first.duration * 1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the [AudioScheduledSourceNode.onended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/onended).

I used four sounds, and put this code in a function:

```
sound1.play();
sound1.onended = function () {
    sound2.play();
};
sound2.onended = function () {
    sound3.play();
};
sound3.onended = function () {
    sound4.play();
}
```

Here is the app live: [insultinator-toy.netlify.app](https://insultinator-toy.netlify.app/)

Click the question mark button.

And the link to the *ugly* source code. [jsahlsa](https://github.com/jsahlsa/insultinator)