# How to make Javascript play certain amount of sounds one AFTER another?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have 4 audio files, and I need them to play in some order, but in a way so they play ONLY when previous has ended playing - one after another.

Here is my attempt

```js
"use strict"

var sound0 = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");
var sound1 = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3");
var sound2 = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3");
var sound3 = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3");

var a = [0, 1, 2, 3];

function play1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] === 0) {
      sound0.play();
    } else if (a[i] === 1) {
      sound1.play();
    } else if (a[i] === 2) {
      sound2.play();
    } else if (a[i] === 3) {
      sound3.play();
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="playBtn" onclick="play1()">Play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127955/how-to-play-a-sound-file-after-another-sound-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326288/html5-audio-playlist-how-to-play-a-second-audio-file-after-the-first-has-ended

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please next time search google for examples. I found more than the 3 I posted

Comment: Try this one, I made a mistake in the last fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/c6s5Lu3r/

Comment: @NewToJS  thanks :) I'll try to make use of it! :)